# Exception Handing Issue

Tags: c++, architecture, exception

I have the C++ application which communicates with a server. It publishes some data to the server, and I got this concern when I'm handling the exceptions for a server failure. I need to handle the exception thrown by the connection when there is an issue with the server, and try to reconnect to the server. I have posted the relevant pseudo-code below:

```
try {
    publisher->publishData(data);
} catch (const ServerDownException& ex) {
    //handle error, reconnect and create a new session
}
```

The concern that I have is, when handling this exception, I need to reconnect and create a session again. The code for creating a session again can throw an exception. So the error handling code will again have a try - catch block inside the original catch block, as follows:

```
try {
    publisher->publishData(data);
} catch (const ServerDownException& ex) {
    publisher->initialize();
    publisher->openSocket();
    try {
        publisher->createSession();
    } catch (const SessionException& tx) {
        //session creation error
    }
    publisher->publishData(data);//after re-connecting, publish data again
}
```

My question is, is it ok to have nested try - catches like this? Else is this just bad design? If so, what can be the best way to achieve this?

PS.: My code is in C++, but I guess the question is general.
Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure the `publisher` should know that it needs to reconnect.

Comment: @PeterWood: can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I think Peter meant that there shouldn't be any exceptions for such a case. If publisher can't publish data it should attempt to reconnect by itself, without throwing exception and having some external entity to reconnect it. But it depends on your code, it is too small piece of it to give some more suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects should be autonomous. They should have all the information they need to act correctly, and references to objects they need to carry out their actions.

`CRC` : `C`lass `R`esponsibility `C`ollaboration.

Objects should be told what to do, not queried and modified by some external object to get them into some correct state. They are responsible for carrying out the action. If they are unable to carry out the action, for some reason they cannot resolve, they should throw an exception (or at least report the error somehow).

Your publisher should only throw an exception if it is unable to publish data. Don't use that exception like a query: *"Oh it's disconnected, it needs to be told to reconnect."*

If it can't resolve the connection problem then it genuinely can throw a `PublishingException`, not a `ServerDown` or `SessionException`.

Your code will then have to handle what to do when you can't publish data. Maybe try publishing in some different way, maybe send emails to administrators. But don't try to reconnect, you already know publishing isn't working.

You could try calling `publishData` again. That would be like a policy: what do we do when publishing doesn't work? The correct place for that policy will depend upon your design.

The `Publisher` could fulfil the policy which you configure it with, like how many times to try reconnecting, whether to keep a cache until the connection succeeds, etc. But all that responsibility would then belong in the publisher and it would only throw an exception if it was unable to fulfil it.

Comment: It's not true. We know nothing about publisher. It can be, say, wrapper around TCP socket, and in this case it should not be autonomous. It all depends on the level of abstraction. And we know nothing about it.

Comment: Wrap the TCP socket so that it can be autonomous.

Comment: And it will lack flexibility which non-autonomous socket has. Such low level entities should not dictate to outer world how it should be used. Maybe I don't want reconnection feature. Or I want it here and don't want it there.

Comment: At some level you wrap `TCP` and make the program autonomous. You could let it fall over every time there is a `TCP` error, just as you could for a `PublishingException`, but you don't. You deal with it. I'm saying deal with the `TCP` exception, and throw a `PublishingException`. Maybe dealing with the `TCP` exception means telling the application the network connection is suspect. The application can then choose how to let the user know.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the suggestions. But there should be a point in code that tells each of the objects what to do isn't it? I'm talking about the business logic of the code.

Comment: @Izza I'm not sure I've said anything otherwise. The business logic is what to do when you can't publish data.

Comment: @Peter: +1, thanks for the explanation. I have modified the code is such a way that autonomy is reflected on the publisher object; it will throw a custom exception when it can't publish data at all, which will be handled at the manager class (where the business logic resides) to notify the user.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to make suggestion based on the only code you posted but, at least, I'd do something like this:

```
while(true){
  try {
      publisher->publishData(data);
      break;
  } catch (const ServerDownException& ex) {
    reconnect(publisher);
  }
}
```

where reconnect consists of

```
publisher->initialize();
publisher->openSocket();
try {
   publisher->createSession();
} catch (const SessionException& tx) {
  //session creation error
}
```